# Linked list add new root element

Tags: c, list, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying to add a new root element to my linked list. I already know the correct answer but I dont understand why there's a double pointer to the current root element. Here's the correct code:

```
void elementAsRoot(Element **oldRoot, Element *newRoot){
  newRoot -> next = *oldRoot;
  *oldRoot = newRoot;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you could just remove the double pointer since you are, in the end, dereferencing the double pointer.

```
void elementAsRoot(Element *oldRoot, Element *newRoot) {
  newRoot->next = oldRoot;
  oldRoot = newRoot;
}
```

Comment: he cannot remove it; the address of oldRoot is not the same as the address of the outside `root` of the list.  They are different pointers poiting to the same address.  If you remove the double pointer it will not mutate the outside address.

Answer (score 1):

I answer you by commenting.  Here is what happens inside `elementAsRoot`.

> `oldRoot` is a pointer to the location/address of the variable that keeps the root of the list in the calling function.  You want to mutate this root inside the `elementAsRoot` and this is why you pass the address of a pointer.

```
void elementAsRoot(Element **oldRoot, Element *newRoot){
```

> first you initialize newRoot to point to the old root

```
  newRoot -> next = *oldRoot;
```

> next, you mutate the old root (defined externally to this function) to point to the new added node.

```
  *oldRoot = newRoot;

}
```

The calling function looks something like

```
Element *root, *newroot;
....  
newroot = malloc(sizeof Element);
// here your list look like root=A => rest .
// This call will mutate root to be new.
elementAsRoot(&root, new);
// here your list look like root=new => A => rest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void elementAsRoot(Element **oldRoot, Element *newRoot){
  newRoot -> next = *oldRoot;
  *oldRoot = newRoot;
}
```

This function is meant to be called like so:

```
Element *list = ...some linked list...;
elementAsRoot(&list, ...some new element...);
// now 'list' points to the new first element, not the old one (which is now second)
```

To update a variable from the caller, the function needs a pointer to the variable. If the first parameter was just `list`, not `&list`, then the function would not be able to update the value of `list` and so it wouldn't be able to do its job.